# How to deal with an unitialized constructor in an if statement (Java)

Tags: java

I've run into a problem where I attempt to define a constructor in the first part of a switch/case statement, and then I can't run the code because the program can't get the definition later.

The idea behind passing the constructor information from a switch/case function is that the user chooses what to do, but for some options, one must be done before the other is possible (e.g. Create password and Check password).

If I try doing it this way, it throws a VarMayNotHaveBeenInitialized error (I get the sense the answer is in a try/catch statement, but I don't know enough about them to be sure). I've included some code that is what I've been essentially trying to do below. (The two classes are to best simulate the project I'm working on.)

Any help is appreciated! : )

TestMain.java:

```
package exitTest;

public class TestMain {
    InitializeTest init;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            String x = InitializeTest.askQuestion();
            
            switch (x) {
                case "set":
                    InitializeTest init = new InitializeTest();
                    break;
                case "get":
                    if (init != null) {
                        init.showExample();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error: init not initialized.");
                    } break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

InitializeTest.java:

```
package exitTest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class InitializeTest {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public InitializeTest thing1;
    public String example;
    
    public static String askQuestion() {
        System.out.println("set for set example\nget for check example");
        String action = in.nextLine();
        return action;
    }
    
    public InitializeTest() {
    System.out.println("Input string:");
    String example = in.nextLine();
    }

    void showExample() { System.out.println(example); }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `init = new InitializeTest();`, not `InitializeTest init = new InitializeTest();`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes; after changing that and making init static, it worked. Do you mind explaining why that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include the type when you're *declaring* variables, not when simply assigning to an existing one. When you write

```
InitializeTest init = new InitializeTest();
```

That makes a *new* `init` variable, unrelated to the previous one, which stores the newly constructed object. That new variable *shadows* the existing one, but it gets released after the `switch` block is over (variables in Java are block-scoped).

To put it to an analogy, it's as though you wanted to tell your friend Alice a secret. But when you went to her house, her neighbor whose name is also Alice happened to be there instead. If you tell *that* Alice your secret, then your friend doesn't find out. Even though the two happen to share a name, they don't share any memory.